# "Connect time out" error for jClouds via proxy

Tags: eclipse, proxy, openstack, jclouds

I am trying to run a simple program of jcloud. The program is as follows:

```
String provider = "openstack-nova";
String identity = "Tenant:usename"; // tenantName:userName
String credential = "pass";

novaApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider).endpoint("http://openstack.infosys.tuwien.ac.at/identity/v2.0")
    .credentials(identity, credential).modules(modules).buildApi(NovaApi.class);
regions = novaApi.getConfiguredRegions();
```

The openstack.infosys is connect via SOCKS proxy on port 7777. I have also enlisted the same on eclipse(Window->Preferences->General->Network Config->SOCKS(Manual)) . However, everytime I run the code I get the following error:

> ERROR o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Command not considered safe to retry because request method is POST:

Which is then caused by

> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I am able to access the horizon web interface of the same without any issues.

Can someone please help me in understanding what is the possible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Apache jclouds about your proxy configuration when creating the context. Have a look at these properties, and pass the ones you need to the `overrides` method of the `ContextBuilder`:

- [Proxy type](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_PROXY_TYPE)
- [Proxy host](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_PROXY_HOST)
- [Proxy port](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_PROXY_PORT)
- [Proxy user](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_PROXY_USER)
- [Proxy password](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_PROXY_PASSWORD)

Comment: You mean like this : 'Properties overrides = new Properties();
 overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_TYPE, "SOCKS");
 overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_HOST, "127.0.0.1");
 overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_PORT, "7777");
 overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO, "true");' I already have this in my code. But its not working

Comment: I didnt do contextBuilder.overrides() . Thanks for all the help. Solved the issue.